# What type is a function name in C?

Tags: c, function

I always understood that in C, `func` and `&func` were equivalent. I assume they should both be of type pointer, which is 8 bytes on my Win64 system. However, I just tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int x, int y)
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(&func), sizeof(func));
    return 0;
}
```

And expecting to get the output `8, 8` was surprised to get `8, 1` instead.

Why is this? What type exactly *is* `func`? It seems to be of type `char` or some equivalent.
What is going on here?

I compiled this with `gcc -std=c99` if it makes a difference.

Comment: `func` is of type "function" and doesn't really have a defined size. `&func` is of type "pointer to a function", so it's size is the size of a pointer.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99` is your friend

Comment: @Mat You forgot `-Werror -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626080/are-there-any-differences-between-these-two-higher-order-function-definitions/18626123#18626123

Comment: @mbratch: Its important to note that function pointers don't necessarily have the same size as object pointers: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> *What type is a function name in C?*

A function name or *function designator* has a function type. When it is used in an expression, except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or `&` operator, it is converted from type "function returning *type*" to type "pointer to a function returning type". (This is specified in C99, 6.3.2.1p4).

Now

`sizeof(func)`

is not valid C as `sizeof` is not allowed with an operand of function type. This is specified in the constraints of the `sizeof` operator:

> (C99, 6.5.3.4p1 Constraints) "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member."

But

`sizeof(func)`

is allowed in GNU C.

There is a GNU extension in GNU C that allows it and in GNU C `sizeof` with an operand of function type yields `1`:

> 6.23 Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers
>
> [...] sizeof is also allowed on void and on function types, and returns 1.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

Comment: Is there any rationale on why they chose to implement this *and* return 1? It seems to me like they created an unnecessary source of confusion.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Because the GNU people are themselves confused. Just look at the C coding style they suggest to follow. Aaaaargh!

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Take a look at the link, this is done in order to allow pointer arithmetic with `void *` and pointer to functions in GNU C.

Comment: @ouah: Pointer arithmetic with `void*` can arguably be useful because you avoid all the casts to `char*` just to advance the pointer when dealing with raw memory. But arithmetic with pointer functions is just evil.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Just speculating, it may be gcc backwards compatibility thing, which they have chosen not to break. Gcc predates C89, after all, so if this behavior was in first gcc, it did not break any standard yet :-)

Answer (score 13):

Given:

```
int func(int x, int y) { /* ... */ }
```

the expression `func` is of function type. Specifically, it's of type `int(int, int)`, which is C's syntax for the type "function with two `int` parameters returning `int`. (You won't often see that particular syntax, since it's not common to refer to function types directly.)

In *most* contexts, an expression of function type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function; in this case, the pointer is of type `int(*)(int, int)`.

The contexts in which this implicit conversion does *not* occur are:

1. When the expression is the operand of unary `&`; in that case, `&func` yields the address of the function (just as `func` by itself *usually* does); and
2. When the expression is the operand of `sizeof`. Without this exception, `sizeof func` would yield the size of a function pointer. Instead, it's a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic from the compiler.

(A side note: This conversion does happen when the function name is used in a function call. The `()` "operator" (the standard doesn't call it that) requires a prefix of pointer-to-function type.)

gcc happens to have a non-standard extension; it permits pointer arithmetic on function pointers and on type `void*`, acting like pointer arithmetic on `char*` pointers (i.e., it operates in units of bytes). Unfortunately, IMHO, gcc did this via a kludge, setting the size of function types and of type `void` to 1. That's why you get `sizeof func == 1`; if you enable one of the standard conforming modes (e.g., `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`), you'll get a warning.

Incidentally, don't use `%d` to print the result of `sizeof`. `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`. If your implementation supports it (C99 or later), use `%zu`; if not, you need to use a cast to explicitly convert the `size_t` value to something that you can print. For example:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof &func);
```

Comment: Where you thinking `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof &func)` in the last paragraph?

Comment: I wonder what the use of pointer arithmetic with a function pointer is supposed to mean. With a `void *` I can understand it, but what is `(funcptr+1)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @glglgl: I've never had any use for it, but perhaps there are some low-level uses for computing the address N bytes before or after the start of a function (if you know how the machine code is laid out), or computing the difference between two function pointers.

Comment: @KeithThompson mmm... very far away from any "defined-ness"... let's hope the GCC guys know what they do...

Comment: (funcptr +1) probably means "Segmentation Fault" the moment you dereference.  It looks pretty fishy to me.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Sure, I don't think 1 is a sensible value to add to a function pointer -- but N might be for some highly system-specific value of N. The fact that gcc does its implementation-specific function pointer arithmetic in terms of bytes makes it easier to work with.

Comment: @glglgl I think this is more of a case, that gcc people hope the C *programmer* knows what he's doing. Which, I suppose, is somewhat in the spirit of C.

Answer (score 5):

> What type is a function name in C?

It's of a **function type.**

> I always understood that in C, `func` and `&func` were equivalent

Well, they are not "equivalent". A function does, however, **decay into** a pointer-to-function.

> I assume they should both be of type pointer

That's an incorrect assumption.

> And expecting to get the output 8, 8 was surprised to get 8, 1 instead. Why is this?

Because 1. it's UB if it compiles, 2. it shouldn't even compile in first place, and as such, your program is free to do anything.

Comment: @Mat Since it's a constraint violation, if it compiles, then it invokes UB. For one thing, it shouldn't compile, but here it apparently does. It does **not** mean that it **must** be an extension/documented.

Comment: @Mat And a program produced by a non-conforming implementation... invokes UB! Or doesn't it? (Oh, and strictly speaking, GCC isn't conforming, unless you do `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -ansi`, perhaps.)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the noise. I was thinking a conforming impl. should not compile, that's not the case, it should diagnose. I have no idea what you can do with the resulting binary if a conforming impl. does produce one after telling you it was rubbish :-)

Comment: @Mat Probably it can be used to confuse two programmers debating about its behavior ;-)

Comment: @Mat I think warning in this case means, "*this* binary has a gcc-specific well-defined behavior, but if you compile it with a different standards conforming compiler, *that* binary might erase all your files". Which is useful if you are fixing old code to be standards compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Names do not have a type in C. Some kinds of names denote entities that have type, such as typedef names, objects or functions. Other kinds of names denote entities that do not have a type, such as preprocessor symbols or `goto` labels. Yet other kind of names simply denote types themselves, namely `typedef` names.

The name of a function denotes an entity that has function type. That function type includes the return type, and (possibly incomplete) information about the parameters.

When functions are used as values, they are always manipulated as pointer-to-function types. A function as such cannot be passed around in a portable C program, but a pointer to a function can be.

Conceptually, even in a direct call like `foo()`, what happens is that `foo`, an expression denoting a function, upon evaluation is implicitly converted to a pointer-to-function value. The `()` function call postfix operator then invokes the function by means of this pointer.

There is a rule that an expression that has function type produces a pointer value, **except** if that expression is the operand of the `&` (address of) or of the `sizeof` operator. `func` and `&func` are only equivalent in the sense that they produce the same value. `func` produces a pointer value implicitly. `&func` suppresses the implicit generation of a pointer (`func` is the operand of `&` and so the conversion is suppressed), but then `&` takes the address.

So you can see that `sizeof &func` and `sizeof func` are different. The former takes the size of a pointer, and the latter tries to take the size of a function.

Taking the size of a function is a constraint violation in C: it requires a diagnostic from an implementation that conforms to the standard.  If the program still translates and a value of `1` is produced when it is run, that is "bonus" behavior specific to your language implementation. It is not in the standard language.