# Trying to understand syntax quirk around dlsym

Tags: c++, macos

I've been trying to pick up some osx programming knowledge to complement my win32 programming experience. I figured out that the rough equivalent of GetProcAddress is dlsym. Then I ran into some unexpected hurdles.

I got my code working after a blur of checking old forum posts and trying things, but it did not match my expectations nor did it match what I saw in Apple's own documentation. I'm hoping someone on here can help me understand why.

[Apple documentation I was referring to](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryUsageGuidelines.html)

The documentation provides an example that looks like this:

```
Person_creator* NewPerson = (Person_creator*)dlsym(lib_handle, "NewPerson");
```

And I got my code working by doing this:

```
void (*printSome)() = (void(*)())dlsym(handle, "printSomething");
```

Where I would have thought my code should have done this:

```
void* printSome = (void*)dlsym(handle, "printSomething");
```

However, when I do that and try to call printSome(), I get this error message:

```
Called object type 'void*' is not a function or function pointer
```

I had a silly thought that it might be something unique to a void function pointer (even though nothing in my experience suggested it would be, I was just grasping trying to understand).

So, what gives? What is the extra syntax doing? Why does this appear nowhere in the official documentation?

Comment: `void *` is a generic pointer. You can not make a function call using a generic pointer. You have to cast it to an appropriate function pointer. Whether you get the pointer from `dlsym()`, or from some other place, it doesn't matter. No matter where you get a pointer from it must be a pointer to a function, and not a generic `void *`.

Comment: What gives is exactly what it says in the error message. `void *` is a pointer. `void (*)()` is a pointer to function.

Comment: `void* printSome` does not declare a function pointer. I'm pretty sure that MSVC wouldn't let you write `printSome()` after this either.

Comment: Note that to be portable, you should write `void (*printSome)(); *(void **)&printSome  = dlsym(handle, "printSomething");`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43509159 for details.

Comment: Thanks all for the fast reply. In diving into @ephemient 's link. I realized that I didn't check the linux man page, just the Apple documentation. And, of course, my syntax question was addressed there.

Comment: @zneak My function pointers in win32 are set up through typedef and define. I guess when I tried to unwind back to basics for learning osx I didn't think through it enough and just took the Apple doc at face value.

Comment: @JRSmith, the Apple doc is still correct. This is simply how you do it without typedefs. Although, yes, typedefs and defines to make function pointer types should also work on macOS.

Comment: @zneak Last follow up question. In Apple doc, they were able to call cast the dlsym-ed function as just (Person_creator*) NewPerson and then later just call NewPerson() without the cast being (Person_creator(*)()). What is my js addled brain missing?

Comment: @JRSmith, `Person_creator` is defined as `typedef Person* Person_creator(void)`, which is a [function typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626123/251153) (rather than a function *pointer* typedef). Therefore, `Person_creator*` is a function pointer, not a pointer to regular data. (JS: not even once! )

Comment: To be clear, when I said "this is how you do it without typedefs", I thought that you referred to the `(void(*)())` syntax. Also, function typedefs are somewhat unusual.

Comment: Oof. I didn't flip back to the class interface. The full path to my self inflicted confusion is now clear to me. (js pays the bills, can't say I'm fond of it though)

Comment: The tl;dr; of the typedef-ed functions is supporting the code checking for version x y or z of saying... the direct input dll. (it also stubs out an error in case no versions can be found). I picked it up watching handmade hero. I'm not 100% attached to it if there's a better way, but it seemed like a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the declaration of a pointer to a function can be confusing. [This website, “cdecl”](https://cdecl.org/), can help you understand what a declaration means. Here's how it explains your working code's variable declaration:

> Input: `void (*printSome)()`
>   Output: declare printSome as pointer to function returning void

And here's how it decodes your non-working code's variable declaration:

> Input: `void* printSome`
>   Output: declare printSome as pointer to void

Notice that the first one declares a pointer to a function while the second one does not. So you cannot perform a function call on the second one.

Using a `typedef` helps simplify the declaration, which is why Apple's documentation uses `typedef Person_creator`. Here's how to use a `typedef` for your code.

First, write out a declaration for a function with the same signature as the function you want to call:

```
void PrintFunction(void);
```

Then stick `typedef` in front of it:

```
typedef void PrintFunction(void);
```

Note that we've declared a *function* type, not a *pointer-to-function* type.

Now you can declare a pointer to this kind of function just like you'd declare a pointer to a non-function type:

```
PrintFunction *printSome;
```

Since `dlsym` is declared to return `void *`, we have to cast its return value. We can use the `typedef` there too:

```
PrintFunction *printSome = (PrintFunction *)dlsym(handle, "printSomething");
```

Note also that C allows you to perform a function call on a pointer-to-function directly, without dereferencing it. So you can call it like this:

```
printSome();
```

which has the same effect as explicitly dereferencing it:

```
(*printSome)();
```

---

#### UPDATE

Since you mentioned (in a comment) that you're watching [Handmade Hero](https://hero.handmade.network/episode/code/day021), I'll explain Casey Muratori's strategy for declaring function types. Let's consider this call at `win32_handmade.cpp:175` from day 21:

```
Result.UpdateAndRender = (game_update_and_render *)
    GetProcAddress(Result.GameCodeDLL, "GameUpdateAndRender");
```

The `UpdateAndRender` field is declared like this at line 157:

```
game_update_and_render *UpdateAndRender;
```

So Casey's using the same `typedef game_update_and_render` to declare the variable and to cast the return value of `GetProcAddress`. (I guess the Windows convention is to use initial upper case for variables and functions, and initial lower case for types, which is the opposite of the Apple convention).

The `typedef game_update_and_render` is at `handmade.h:190`:

```
typedef GAME_UPDATE_AND_RENDER(game_update_and_render);
```

It uses the `GAME_UPDATE_AND_RENDER` macro declared on the prior line:

```
#define GAME_UPDATE_AND_RENDER(name) void name(game_memory *Memory, game_input *Input, game_offscreen_buffer *Buffer)
```

Ultimately, `game_update_and_render` is a `typedef` for a function type, just like `Person_creator` in Apple's example or my `PrintFunction` above.

Why does Casey use the `GAME_UPDATE_AND_RENDER` macro? I guess it's because then he can use the same macro to define an actual function of that type, like he does on the next line (`handmade.h:190`):

```
GAME_UPDATE_AND_RENDER(GameUpdateAndRenderStub)
{
}
```

Here he's defining a function named `GameUpdateAndRenderStub`, with the same signature (argument and return types) as `typedef game_update_and_render`. Without the macro, he'd have to repeat the argument and return types like this:

```
void GameUpdateAndRenderStub(game_memory *Memory, game_input *Input, game_offscreen_buffer *Buffer)
{
}
```

Comment: I sussed out how I confused myself in the comments above. But this is a nice thorough answer. I'm going to mark it. Thanks for the effort. Hopefully this saves someone else in the future.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an explanation of how Casey declares his function typedefs in Handmade Hero.